# How to set the 'value' parameter for a hidden field in runtime in Turbogears

Tags: python, turbogears, toscawidgets

In order to set the value for a HiddenField in toscawidget, the only parameter I've found useful is 'default' (surprisingly, parameter 'value' in toscawidgets doesn't represent 'value' in html). However, the only way I could get it working is at the time of field creation:

```
class myForm(TableForm):
    class fields(WidgetsList): 
    myhiddenField = HiddenField(default='old_value')
```

However, I need to be filled in runtime, or in other words, I want my controller to change the value of the hidden field in runtime. but it seems impossible, and

```
child_args=dict(myHiddenField = dict(default = 'new_value'))
```

doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it should be sufficient to supply the value in the options dict when you render the form in your template.

```
myform(dict(myHiddenField=dict(default='new_value')))
```

No need for `child_args` here.